# Ubuntu 18.04.02 AMDGPU installation problems

Tags: 18.04, amdgpu

I've been trying for hours to install the AMDGPU drivers on my PC with Ubuntu 18.04.02 (I was on 18.10 originally but apparently AMDGPU doesn't support that). And now when I try to install, I get a message saying "amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel". My kernel version is Linux 4.18.0-17-generic. Is there a way to fix this?

This is after running amdgpu-install. Also, should I be running amdgpu-pro-install after, before, or not at all?

P.S: after getting this warning and re-booting, I go into a login loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the kernel in Ubuntu 18.04 is too new for the dkms module, so it fails to build correctly. Unfortunately, there's no easy solution that I've found. You can try to run an older kernel (4.10 works, but it's not in the main 18.04 repo so you'll have to download it yourself), or you can just use the built-in driver until they update the amdgpu kernel module for newer kernels.